# Apache Airflow Task timeout

Tags: airflow, etl

So i have a test dag of one task, which is simple ETL try to extract data from mssql db and load them to postgres db. so in the way it working is select by date and insert to postgres db for the last 360 days. but the task is timeout on the select statement after say 10 days or so.

```
def get_receiveCars(**kwargs):
    #get current date
    end_date = datetime.now()
    #loop for 360 days
    for x in range(360):
        startDate = today - timedelta(days=x)
        delete_dataPostgres(startDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), "received sample")
        select_dataMsql(startDate)
```

and the select statement is:

```
def select_dataMsql(startDate):
    #insert data
    endDate = str(startDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + " 23:59:59"
    ms_hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id='mssql_db')
    select_sql="""select  carColor, carBrand, fuelType, COUNT(DISTINCT RequestID ) AS received 
    FROM Requests 
    where  
    ReceivedDateTime >= %s 
    AND  ReceivedDateTime< %s 
    GROUP BY carColor, carBrand, fuelType"""
    cond = (startDate, endDate)
    results =ms_hook.get_records(select_sql, parameters=cond)
    insert_data(results, startDate)
```

and here is my dag

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from src.get_receiveCars import get_receiveCars
#from src.transform_data import transform_data
#from src.load_table import load_table
import requests
import json
import os


# Define the default dag arguments.
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': XXXXX,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}


# Define the dag, the start date and how frequently it runs.
# I chose the dag to run everday by using 1440 minutes.
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='reveive_sample',
    default_args=default_args,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=200),
    schedule_interval= '@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 10, 30))


# First task is to query get the weather from openweathermap.org.
mid_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_receiveCars',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_receiveCars,
    dag=dag)

# Set task1 
mid_task
```

**LOGS**

```
- Start syncing user roles.
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,238] {timeout.py:42} ERROR - Process timed out, PID: 84214
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,238] {dagbag.py:259} ERROR - Failed to import: /root/airflow/dags/receive_sample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/airflow/dags/receive_sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.get_receiveCars import get_receiveCars
  File "/root/airflow/dags/src/get_receiveCars.py", line 56, in <module>
    get_receiveCars()
  File "/root/airflow/dags/src/get_receiveCars.py", line 17, in get_receiveCars
    delete_data(startDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), "received cars")
  File "/root/airflow/dags/src/get_receiveCars.py", line 26, in delete_data
    pg_hook.run(delete_sql, parameters=cond)
  File "/root/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 172, in run
    cur.execute(s, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 15, in decode
    def decode(input, errors='strict'):
  File "/root/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 43, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: Timeout, PID: 84214
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,260] {security.py:477} INFO - Start syncing user roles.
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,350] {security.py:477} INFO - Start syncing user roles.
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,494] {security.py:387} INFO - Fetching a set of all permission, view_menu from FAB meta-table
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,550] {security.py:387} INFO - Fetching a set of all permission, view_menu from FAB meta-table
[2020-10-30 18:29:40,639] {security.py:387} INFO - Fetching a set of all per
```

Comment: Just to get this right, your DAG is running on a single run for 10 days?

Comment: no, the DAG run once per day, but get_receiveCars has a loop of 360, which count as days.. but when loop is on 10/360 days is when timeout happens

Comment: Makes sense, what's printed in the logs?

Comment: i have added the logs

Answer (score 3):

Check your configuration:

```
airflow config list|grep -i timeout
```

```
dagbag_import_timeout = 30
dag_file_processor_timeout = 50
web_server_master_timeout = 120
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5
smtp_timeout = 30
operation_timeout = 1.0
task_adoption_timeout = 600
```

You'll want to change the dagbag_import_timeout setting so it has time to load your dag.

To do this update your airflow.cfg file or set the environment variable:

```
export AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT=300
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are in queued state and getting killed externally, then add env variable :
`AIRFLOW__CELERY__OPERATION_TIMEOUT: "30"`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a [`execution_timeout`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html) in your `default_args` - I would start with that:

> **execution_timeout (datetime.timedelta)** – max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.

[`dagrun_timeout`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html) has a different meaning:

> **dagrun_timeout (datetime.timedelta)** – specify how long a DagRun should be up before timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. The timeout is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns, and only once the # of active DagRuns == max_active_runs.

Comment: Is it always killed after the same time? Is it possible that one of the databases kills the queries?

Comment: i think you are right, since there is a loop, number connections becoming too many.